# org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope

Tags: android, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am trying to hit soap api in my application for login purpose , but getting above mentioned error  , Can any one tell me that where i am going wrong , Its my first time with soap apis.
here is my code to hit Soap :-

```html
Vector<Object> args = new Vector<Object>();
   Hashtable<String, Object> hashtable = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
   hashtable.put("Email", "mss.siddhart28@gmail.com");
   hashtable.put("Password", "siddharth");
   args.add(hashtable);
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
   envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
   (new MarshalHashtable()).register(envelope);
   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
     "http://tempuri.org/", 15000);
   androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
   String result = "";
   try {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://tempuri.org", "call");
    request.addProperty("resourcePath", "User_Login");
     request.addProperty("args", args);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    androidHttpTransport.call("call", envelope);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "envelope is" + envelope, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    System.out.println("result signup: " + result);
   } catch (EOFException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "restart";
   }
```

And here is my wsdl :-

```html
POST /w4w/w4wservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: 64.31.2.58
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/User_Login"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <User_Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Email>string</Email>
      <Password>string</Password>
    </User_Login>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Finally I solve My Problem .. here i am posting code so that others can get help.

```html
private   String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/User_Login";
 private   String METHOD_NAME = "User_Login";
 private   String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
 private   String URL = "http://64.31.2.58:8080/w4w/w4wservice.asmx";
```

```html
public String logIn() {
   
   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER11);
   envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.xsd = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;
   envelope.enc = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC;
   (new MarshalHashtable()).register(envelope);
   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
     URL, 15000);
   androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
   String result = "";
   try {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,
      METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("Email", Email);
    request.addProperty("Password", Password);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    result = envelope.getResponse().toString();
    
    System.out.println("result signup: " + result);
   } catch (EOFException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "restart";
   } catch (SoapFault e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    if (e.getMessage()
      .contains("Session expired. Try to re-login.")) {
     return "restart";
    }
    return "Email Already Exists";
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "restart";
   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return "";
   }
   System.out.println("registration result :" + result);
   return result;

  }
```